# How to put checkbox values into a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms

I am having trouble getting the values from checkboxes into my database, it just shows up as 'Array' when submitted to the database.

Here are snippets of my code that illustrate what I am trying to do:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="commentType[]" id="Streams_Wetlands" value="Streams_Wetlands">
<input type="checkbox" name="commentType[]" id="Vegetation" value="Vegetation">
```

JS:

```
 var commentType = new Array(); 
 $('input:checkbox[name="commentType[]"]').each(function() {
       commentType.push($(this).val());
 });

 postData( "php/add1.php",{
    CommentAddress1: commentAddress1,
    UserAddress1: userAddress1,
    CommentType1: commentType,
    CommentTypeOther1: commentTypeOther1
  });
```

PHP:

```
$q .= " . $_POST['UserAddress1'] . "','" . $_POST['CommentType1'] . "','" . $_POST['CommentTypeOther1'] . "','" . $_POST['CommentAddress1'] . ";
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON encode the array before storing it into database.

```
var commentType = new Array(); 
 $('input:checkbox[name="commentType[]"]').each(function() {
       commentType.push($(this).val());
 });

 var comments = JSON.stringify(commentType);
```

Then store the json string into database.

As usual you'll run a query to fetch data from database. Since you stored it as a json string into database, you can't use it as an array. In order to convert the json string back to an array, use `json_decode()`.

```
$CommentsArray = json_decode($commentJsonStringFromDB, true);
```

Why we did all this ? Because we had to serialise the array before storing it into database, Why ? Because by serialising, we :

> Generates a storable representation of a value. This is useful for
>   storing or passing PHP values around without losing their type and
>   structure.

Comment: What is $someJsonString? I don't understand the second part about decoding the JSON.

Comment: So this is now adding the values to my database, but includes ["",""]... like this: ["Agricultural","Grazing","Biological","Streams_Wetlands","Vegetation","Safety","Noise","ProtectedSpecies","Property","ConstructionGeneral","GroundDisturbance","RightOfWayAccess","VisualImpact","Other"].  How do I get rid of the formatting and just have a comma separated list?

Comment: That is json string format. The advance of storing it as a json string instead of comma separted values is that, you can always convert it back to an array easily using default php functions, as I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Okay, but I need to send it to the database as an array. How would I do that?

Comment: You have to serialise an array in order to store it into database, that why we encode it into json.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean, but this doesn't help me. This is a SQL database and does not require serialized data. Also this code is sending every checkbox to the database, not just the checked ones.

Comment: What I've suggested is a way to store an array into a **SINGLE field**, as far as I know, this is the only way to do it.